# Cython: def without argument inside cdef class: gcc warning not a prototype

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, gcc-warning

I have a `cdef class` which contains a static `def method` without argument. For example:

```
cdef class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        pass
```

Unfortunately, when I compile this, I have a warning telling the the function declaration is not a prototype:

```
$ echo "import pyximport; pyximport.install(); import test_pyx;" | python3
[...]/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyrex/test_pyx.c:673:1:
warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 static PyObject *__pyx_pf_8test_pyx_4Test_test(); /* proto */
 ^
```

In my opinion, it sounds clear that the C function should take at least one argument, which is `void` in this case. Unfortunately, I can't define a void argument in the `def` method.

On the other hand, I have no way to use a `cpdef` method because the `@staticmethod` annotation is not (yet) supported in cython.

How should I proceed to avoid that warning (I'm using a -Werror flag when building production environment package)?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I doubt if you can unfortunately. I don't think Cython is built for the sake of avoiding all warnings. If you really can't turn off -Werror you could run cython as the first step, manually edit the file (or write a script that edits the file) to add `void`, and then compile with C. But that's hardly a solution.

Comment: Alternatively, you could get Cython to generate c++ code (call as `cython --cplus filename` or `# distutils: language = c++` at the top of your pyx file), since that prototype form is legal in c++. I'd be surprised if that was your only warning though.

Comment: Thanks. That was my fear, indeed. I've remove that static method from the class so that the warning is not triggered anymore. In addition, I've added an option to avoid this warning becoming an error (in my CFLAGS environment variable).

Comment: @MichaelHooreman perhaps you could close this question posting your comments as an answer...

Comment: @SaulloCastro Sure, but I can't find out how...